# Check if array elements are in a different array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function to return true if all items in $array1 are in $array2, if not return false.

What I'm trying to do:

```
$array1 = ['1', '3', '9', '17'];
$array2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '9', '11', '12', '17'];

function checkArray($arr, $arr2) {
    If all elements in $arr are in $arr2 return true
    else return false
}

if (checkArray($array1, $array2) {
    // Function returned true
} else {
    // Function returned false
}
```

I can't think of how to do this! Help much appreciated.

SOLUTION:

```
function checkArray($needles, $haystack) {
    $x = array_diff($needles, $haystack);
    if (count($x) > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
// Returns false because more needles were found than in haystack
checkArray([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]); 
// Returns true because all needles were found in haystack
checkArray([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Comment: Why not just use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) ???

Comment: Didn't know about this, feel like an eejit now lol :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function checkArray($arr, $arr2) {
    return !count(array_diff($arr, $arr2));
}
```

**array_diff**: Returns an array containing all the entries from `$arr` that are not present in `$arr2`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Didn't find this when searching!! Ahh you're a legend, good man cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure as to how array_diff is useful in any way.
So who cares if there are diferences? You are not comparing arrays, or at least that's not what I understand in the question. You want to know if one array **contains** the other.

PHP has a handy function for that

```
function checkArray($arr, $arr2) {
    return (array_intersect($arr, $arr2) == $arr);
}
```

Comment: Now you've confused me... Gonna give this array_diff a try. I also got my problem solved in a totally different way but definitely far from the best solution!

Comment: array_dif will give you an array containing differences. But you want to know if one array values are contained in the other, right? Running array_diff just by itself won't give you much.

Comment: Well if the count of the differences is greater than zero then not everything in $array1 was found in $array2. Or at least that's how I'm interpreting it! either way both have taught me something new :)

Comment: @Think array_diff([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]) is empty. It won't return that [4].

Comment: @joeframbach Of course not, why would I? (Plus don't have priviledges for that yet). I did try array_diff and it turns out it doesn't work exactly as I expected. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Modified the question to reflect my solution! Thanks all for the help :)